# WordPress: How to send email to user when user has no activity on website

Tags: php, wordpress

Can Any one suggest me how I can send an automated email to that user who has didn't active in website from pass 15 days or month.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could setup a cron job, daily which checks that for you and then send an email..

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how i will record the user is active or not

Comment: you are saying first i logged each user by any plugin then set a cron jobs for sending email at certain time period? Am I right

Comment: I'm saying you probably have a database with users, and some column with: datetime when the last time it was when he logged... Then in a cron you query those who havn't logged in for 14 days and you good to go

Comment: Ok thank you so much,if it is possible can you send me any tutorial link that how i will create cron job